# How to replace mocha UTF8 checkmark symbol in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, utf-8, mocha.js

When I run the mocha tests in jenkins, on the console output I can see `â` insetad of the `✓` (CHECK MARK) utf-8 character.

[image]

How can I replace these symbols to human readable format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Modify default reporter

The easiest way, to modify the [default reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/base.js) of the mocha in the helper.js

#### helper.js

```
const mocha = require("mocha");
mocha.reporters.Base.symbols.ok = "[PASS]";
mocha.reporters.Base.symbols.err = "[FAIL]";
```

#### package.json

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "test": "mocha --require helpers.js"
    }
}
```

### Use different reporter

Also you can use other reporters https://mochajs.org/#reporters

Answer (score 0):

on karma.conf.js change the success mark

add those options:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

// reporters configuration

reporters: ['mocha'],

// reporter options

mochaReporter: {
  symbols: {
    success: '+',
    info: '#',
    warning: '!',
    error: 'x'
  }
}
```

for more info use this link:
[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter)

this will generate the reports like so:

```
 spec name
    + first test
    + second test
    + third test
```

instead of the defaults with the strange check mark symbol:

```
 spec name
        √ first test
        √ second test
        √ third test
```